# Reading line by line from file in java

Tags: java

I have problems with BufferedReader in java. I am reading line by line from large file, parsing lines and inserting into HashMap, but in the result only few lines are in HashMap

```
Map< Integer, String> data = new HashMap<>(1000000);
    int completedTestsCount = 0;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"), 120000);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.contains("START executing FOR"))
        {                   
            String tempId = line.substring(42, line.length() - 38);
            int startId = Integer.parseInt(tempId);
            String dateTime = line.substring(6, 14);
            data.put(startId, dateTime);                
        }
```

And it's an example of line from file that I want to parse "INFO  00:00:09 - START executing FOR  test3625 at Mon Sep 23 00:00:09 GMT+00:00 2013", so keys are test id

Comment: What keys do you use? can you add some code?

Comment: Can you post the code that you used? That way we can help you in which part of it you went wrong. =)

Comment: There are various reasons why this could happen, but all we can say is "You've got a bug" until you show some code.

Comment: Please share the code snippet.

Comment: are you using same keys multiple times

Comment: Can a large file do that??

Comment: @javaBeginner feel free to flag comments if you think they are rude, but your comments don't add any value to the post.

Answer (score 3):

HashMap saves data as ,  where key is unique, so may in your case,

```
String tempId = line.substring(42, line.length() - 38);
```

is the key, and as you are reading it from file, this might not be unique. This is the problem, you have to make sure key is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that lots of lines in the file have the same `startId`.  Each time you `put` a key/value pair with the same key, you will actually *replace* the previous map entry for that key.  (A `Map` maps one key to exactly one value ...)

This might be because the ids are *genuinely* the same, or it might be that the way you are extracting the id from each line is incorrect; e.g. if the actual id doesn't always start at character 42.

By my counting, character 42 of your example line is the `2` in `3625` ... and that does not seem correct!

Answer (score 0):

For using HashMaps, you will need all the `stardId` values to be unique.

You should be using a list, instead of a map in this case.

Define a custom `KeyValuePair` class and add the objects in the list.

```
class KeyValuePair{
    int startId;
    String dateTime; 
}

List<KeyValuePair> data = new ArrayList<>();


String tempId = line.substring(42, line.length() - 38);
int startId = Integer.parseInt(tempId);
String dateTime = line.substring(6, 14);
data.add(new KeyValuePair(startId, dateTime))
```

Comment: You are assuming that the keys are really non-unique.  There is an alternative explanation for the OP's problem; i.e. that his "logic" for extracting the keys is incorrect.

Comment: I need a dataStructure where insert , find and delete operations are ~ O(1)